# Как выбрать файл и скопировать в другую папку, с динамическим конечным путем

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Нужно через OpenFileDialog выбрать файл (Кнопка Выбрать)

В чеклисте выбрать путь, куда переносить файл.
Путь этот находится в удаленной папке.

Но поскольку мы не знаем заранее, в какую папку нужно будет отправлять файл, я сделал 3 текстбокса, в которые можно написать названия папок.

Например, в чеклисте у нас "\\192.168.0.1\base", мы в текстбокс дописываем название папки(Папка1) и путь получается аля "\\192.168.0.1\base\Папка1".
И при нажатии кнопки "Скопировать", копируется выбранный файл, в указанный каталог. Не смейтесь пожалуйста над способом) Лучше не придумал) И примерные шаги на фото.
Выбрали файл.

Указали каталог

Дополнили путь

Скопировали.

Будьте добры, подскажите, как это копирование с выбором написать. Спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примеров кода нет. Только формирование списка путей. Эта программа должна будет взять 1 файл и отправить его в несколько папок сразу. (магазинные сервера)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К примеру есть у вас исходный путь `string`, и есть пути назначения `List<string>`. Для отображения выбранного файла достаточно одной `Label`. Если файлов много, можно `ListBox` попробовать, либо что-то свое написать.

Для создания и редактирования путей назначения можно использовать например `DataGridView`, состоящую из одной или нескольких колонок. Либо `ListBox`/`ListView` и кнопки - вам решать.

Чтобы не умирать над позиционированием контролов - познакомьтесь с панелями `FlowLayoutPanel` и `TableLayoutPanel`.

Тогда метод копирования будет выглядеть так:

```cs
public void CopyToAllTargets(string srcPath, List<string> dstPaths)
{
    foreach (string dstPath in dstPaths)
    {
        File.Copy(srcPath, dstPath);
    }
}
```

Это самая простая реализация, которая поочередно копирует один и тот же файл в разные каталоги.

Можно делать это одновременно, в потоках или асинхронно, реализовать алгоритм по шаблону Producer/Consumer, чтобы запись велась со скоростью принимающего, а не самого медленного получателя. Много чего можно сделать, зависит от ваших потребностей и возможностей способов передачи данных.

*Возьмите на заметку: сначала пишется функциональная часть, а потом красота в интерфейсе наводится - не наоборот. Иначе вы потратите кучу времени на интерфейс, а функциональная часть останется пустая, будет красиво выглядеть и ничего не уметь. Либо при написании функциональной части вы поймете, что интерфейс надо переписывать заново. Лепите интерфейс как попало, экономьте время. А уже потом, когда это страшилище будет уметь делать все или почти все что вам надо - принимайтесь за красоту. Красота в Winforms - дело сложное, может занять много времени. (поэтому я предпочитаю WPF)*

Comment: Космос. Никакой воды. Спасибо Вам